# C Code not working properly if function

Tags: c

my string is XAbc, and the first character is X. in my IF function if first=X symbol = 0, but i printf symbol and it gives me symbol = 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    checkformula("XAbc");

}
void checkformula(char* formula)
{
    char first = formula[0];
    int symbol;

printf("first character is %c\n",first);
    if (first = 'E')
    {
          symbol = 2;
    } else if (first = "~")
    {
         symbol = 1;
    } else if (first = 'X'){
        symbol = 0;
    } else if (first = 'A')
    {
          symbol = 3;
    } else if  (first = '(')
    {
        symbol = 4;

    } else {
        symbol = -1;
        }


printf("symbol is %i\n", symbol);
```

OUTPUT:

first character is X
symbol is 2

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, `==` is the equality operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You if statements are wrong.  Don't you mean to be using "==" not "=" operator?  You are doing an assignment instead of a compare.

```
if (first == 'E')
    {
          symbol = 2;
    } else if (first == "~")
    {
  //etc
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `if` statements, you need to test for equality with the `==` operator. As it is, you are using the assignment operator, `=`, which is modifying the value of your variables on the left-hand side and providing a "true" value to the `if` so long as the character on the right-hand side is not the ASCII NUL (`'\0'`) character -- "zero" values are `false` and non-zero values are `true` in C.

Answer (score 1):

- Your code invokes **undefined behavior** as it has no prototype for your function `checkformula`.  Place a prototype for the function before main.

It should be like:

```
void checkformula(char *);
```

- You are using assignment operator `=` in `if` statements instead of `==` operator.

It should be

```
if (first == 'E') {...}
```